# How can I move flexslider's thumbnail controlnav above the main slider?

Tags: jquery, slider, flexslider

I am using a Flexslider 2 with thumbail controlnav, exactly like in the [example](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html), but I want the thumbnails to be above the main slider, not below. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

BTW I will totally accept X slider makes this super easy as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this would be a problem. You just need to edit some CSS Code. 
I tried this with firebug in my Browser:

```
.flex-control-thumbs { margin: -185px 0 0; } // height of the thumb-nav

.flex-control-nav { position: absolute !important; }
```

I've not downloaded the slider to test this, but i hope this will help you. ;)